# Comparing string and HTML in Java

Tags: java, html, string-comparison

I'm trying to compare a line of HTML and a string of HTML containing a variable.  However, my method keeps returning FALSE when it should return TRUE.

```
//textLineToCheck contains the HTML string

public static boolean checkWhiteList(String textLineToCheck, String nameOfPerson) {
    textLineToCheck=textLineToCheck.trim();
    textLineToCheck=textLineToCheck.toLowerCase();
    boolean isOfValue=false;
    if (textLineToCheck.equals("<h2 class='altResource'>"+nameOfPerson+"</h2>")) {
        isOfValue=true;
    }
    return isOfValue;
} //end checkWhiteList()
```

Comment: Note: nameOfPerson is in lowercase

Comment: It appears the HTML code is being stripped out.  I assure you it's accurate.

Comment: Can you give us the value of `textLineToCheck` also instead of using `isOfValue` you can also return the expression `textLineToCheck.equals("<h2 class='altResource'>"+nameOfPerson+"</h2>")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem lies when you do lower case on `textLineToCheck`

Suppose you have
`textLineToCheck = <h2 class='altResource'>abc</h2>"` and

```
nameOfPerson = "abc"
```

And when you perform
`textLineToCheck=textLineToCheck.toLowerCase();`

it will be 
`textLineToCheck = <h2 class='altresource'>abc</h2>"`  (Note small `r` in `altresource`)

and then if you compare it with nameOfPerson, you are comparing

`textLineToCheck = <h2 class='altresource'>abc</h2>"` and
`<h2 class='altResource'>abc</h2>"`

which will obviously return `false`

Comment: Yup, this looks like the reason.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in a big R, in altResource. And you are comparing it to a lower case string.